# iPhone Wrapping Text In UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, word-wrap

I am trying to create a UITableView cell that says "View this devotional online" with a large font.  The issue I am having is the text in the cell is not wrapping so I end up with part of the phrase.

[image: text not wrapping]

The code I have for this is:

```
// Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Get cell
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"CellA";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
}

// Display
cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
if (item) {

    // Item Info
    NSString *itemTitle = item.title ? [item.title stringByConvertingHTMLToPlainText] : @"[No Title]";

    // Display
    switch (indexPath.section) {
        case SectionHeader: {

            // Header
            switch (indexPath.row) {
                case SectionHeaderTitle:
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
                    cell.textLabel.text = itemTitle;
                    break;
                case SectionHeaderDate:
                    cell.textLabel.text = dateString ? dateString : @"[No Date]";
                    break;
                case SectionHeaderURL:
                    cell.textLabel.text = @"View this devotional in full website";
                    cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:36];
                    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Safari.png"];
                    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline
                    break;
            }
            break;

        }
        case SectionDetail: {

            // Summary
            cell.textLabel.text = summaryString;
            cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline
            break;

        }
    }
}

return cell;

}
```

The following line worked before, but it doesn't seem to work here.

`cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0; // Multiline`

Could someone show me how to wrap my text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to setting `numberOfLines` to zero, set the line break mode:

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
```

(uncompiled, but you get the idea).

Comment: Indeed, so now you have to provide a custom height for that cell using `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:`. In fact, however, you will need to provide a height for every row and a special height for this special row when you implement this method.

Comment: You don't need to calculate height for each row, though. If you want to use the default height, just return `tableview.rowHeight`.

Comment: cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2

Answer (score 7):

As of iOS6, UILineBreakModeWordWrap is deprecated. You'll need-

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
```